# Excel 2013 - Filling Zeroes based on Row/Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on cleaning up timesheets for an Access database, and I'm having issues with cleaning up the data.

I have a time sheet with names in the first column, then all of the columns after that, from C to M (or so) have hours. What I am trying to accomplish is that when the Macro finds a name in the first column, it selects the columns in that row, finds the cells without hours, and fills them with zeroes

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Range

    For r = 2 To 15 Step 1
        If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, 10)).Select
        End If
    Next

    For Each c In Selection
        If IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.Value = 0
        End If
    Next
```

I'm attempting to loop and fill rows with zeroes based on the cell having a named entered in it.  The problem that I'm running into is that cells are only being filled in the last name/row in the spreadsheet.  The macro seems to be skipping over all but the last row.

I'm just learning VBA, so maybe I'm just missing something in the syntax.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Will you have *zero-length strings* returned by formulas? These are not considered truly blank but can be compensated for.

Comment: Line 4 should be `If Cells(r, 1).Value`. The cell's content is available in the `.Value` property.

Comment: @nhee, It still has the same problem.

Jeeped, The first column will always have a name/short text in it, nothing else.

Comment: Please explain your "clean up rules".

Comment: So I have a time sheet with Names in the first column, then all of the columns after that, from C to M or so have hours.  What I am trying to accomplish is that when the Macro finds a name in the first column, it selects the columns in that row, finds the cells without hours, and fills them with zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are moving on to the next selection, all the way to the last row, before you start filling in your 0s. Try this modification to your code:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Range

For r = 2 To 15 Step 1
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, 10)).Select
    End If
    For Each c In Selection
        If IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.Value = 0
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

Using this method, you fill in the 0s before moving on to the next selection/row.

Note: I avoid the use of .select/Selection because of the problems it can cause, so I am not sure if you will receive an error message if a row does not contain a name. If you wish to avoid this potential error, try the below:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim c2 As Range

For r = 2 To 15 Step 1
    If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
        Set c2 = Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, 10))
    End If
    For Each c In c2
        If IsEmpty(c) Then
            c.Value = 0
        End If
    Next c
Next r
```

By the way, did you strip out the Workbook and Sheet names from `Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, 10))` to simplify your post? I was surprised you were able to use that without errors. If so, you'd obviously have to put them back in for my code to work.

Comment: Used without qualifiers, `Range` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Range` and `Cells` is the same as `ActiveSheet.Cells`. This makes the code dependent on a specific sheet being active and thus increases the possibility of error. It's definitely preferable to consistently qualify calls to `Range` and `Cells`

Comment: This worked great.  Thanks!

I'm having trouble understanding VBA syntax, but slowly learning.  I'm getting confused sometimes with code blocks and making sure For has a Next and IF has an END IF.

Comment: Good, I am glad you got it! :)

Comment: Is there a reason that it's "next c" or "next r" instead of just next?  I keep seeing both.

Comment: I am not positive, but I'm guessing it's to help you keep track of which loop you are in. As you probably see already, I have the c loop inside of the r loop, so even if it serves no functional purpose, it helps you see that every c is being processed before moving on to the next r, then all the c's are processed again, etc.

Answer (score 0):

possibly,

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Rws = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rws, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Rng = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to take all of the blank cells and turn them into zeroes.

```
Sub zeroed_hours()
    Dim rw As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")    '<-set this worksheet reference properly!
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Len(.Cells(rw, 1))) Then 'found a name!
                'C:M on this row
                .Cells(rw, 3).Resize(1, 11).Replace what:="", replacement:=0, lookat:=xlWhole
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Sub
```

This loops through the cells in column A. If it finds a value (something with length greater than zero) then it replaces all blank cells in C:M on that row with zeroes.

Comment: I only want to fill with zeroes in empty cells in specific rows that have a name in the first column.